# I have a splunk cloud account, Now I want my java application's logs to be stored on splunk cloud. I am wondering How can I do that?

Tags: java, splunk

I have a splunk cloud account, Now I want my java application's logs to be stored on splunk cloud. I am wondering How can I do that Splunk cloud integration with java application's log

Comment: You really need to try google first. Try some things out and if you still have a problem come back and show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different options for ingesting log data with Splunk.

Two of the most common solutions for java based applications are:

- [Configure a splunk forwarder](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/6.5.1612/User/DataSplunkCloudcanindex) on the instance hosting the application that reads the logs and forwards them to your splunk cloud.
- Use the [custom logging appenders](http://dev.splunk.com/view/splunk-logging-java/SP-CAAAE2K) provided by splunk.